# Entity Framework Core Create Multi Value Attribute (List of items inside and Entity)

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I'm developing a `WPF desktop application` with `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite` and I have this entity `Room` which has multi value attribute called `NotAvailableTimes` there can be multiple `NotAvailableTimes` for one room. I tried to implement a list but according to my research EFCORE doesn't support that. Is there Any easy way to implement this ?

I even Tried creating another Entity and add one to many relationship between two Entities but i don't know how to insert data into the list of the first entity.

**Room Class**

```
public class Room
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Rid { get; set; }
    public Building BuildingAS { get; set; }
    public String Type { get; set; }
    public int Capacity { get; set; }

    public IList<RoomNAT> RoomNATs { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RoomLecturer> RoomLecturers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RoomSubject> RoomSubjects { get; set; }

}
```

**my wrapper class**

```
public class RoomNAT
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public String StartTime { get; set; }    
    public String EndTime { get; set; }    
    public String Day { get; set; }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is basically the same as the `RoomLectures`: make it an ICollection and mark it as virtual. It's indeed a one-to-many relation.

```
public virtual ICollection<RoomNATs> RoomNATs { get; set; }
```

You'll need to migrate/update the database after this since it will generate an table containing the information.

As for this part:

> I even Tried creating another Entity and add one to many relationship between two Entities but i don't know how to insert data into the list of the first entity.

It's also just similar to the normal inserts:

```
_context.Rooms.RoomNATs.Add(new RoomNAT() { 
   //init properties
});

_context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not map it in database unless its a virtual property make it virtual it should work fine and make roomNats a separate table and add foreign key constraint as well.

```
 public class RoomNAT
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public String StartTime { get; set; }

    public String EndTime { get; set; }

    public String Day { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Room> Rooms{ get; set; }
}

    public class Room
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Rid { get; set; }
    public Building BuildingAS { get; set; }
    public String Type { get; set; }
    public int Capacity { get; set; }

    public virtual RoomNAT RoomNATs { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RoomLecturer> RoomLecturers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RoomSubject> RoomSubjects { get; set; }

}
```

Here relation is one to many
if you want many to one or many to many you can change it to **Ilist** now